# WCF Design Principle: Is it a good idea to edit auto-generated proxy classes?

Tags: c#, wcf

This question might be too naive. I am very much new to WCF.

I have an auto-generated WCF proxy class with all the DataContracts in it. The DataContracts also have some response classes. Each class has a default no-parameterized constructor which eventually does nothing. I want to initialize a few members of the class so that I can set those properties as default and I don't have to set it everytime I need to use it.

I noted that the proxy classes are marked as partial. So I thought of creating another class file which will add to these response classes. But then I can't override the default constructor of-course.

What do you suggest? Should I edit the auto-generated proxy classes itself or is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: I think the real question is _whether you should be using VS-auto-generated proxy classes in the first place?_  http://www.codemag.com/article/0809101

Comment: I went through the article. This one too applies majorly to the times when you are maintaining both the service and the client side. In scenarios when you are just the consumer of a service then you would need to use auto-generated proxy classes, isn't it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes so long as your customer is generating client proxies from a SOAP WSDL that you have provided them.  Visual Studio has it wrong where the WSDL is defined after the fact.  The latter just leads to portability issues

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have* to use generated proxy classes at all. You could define your data contract classes and service interfaces in *contracts-only .dll* and refer to that in projects that need access to the types and interfaces. This isn't a whole lot different than what the proxy provides in some sense.

Then, in your client projects, you can create instances of the service proxy using a `ChannelFactory<IService>`. I really prefer this to using the generated proxies. To create a service channel factory, you could do something like:

```
private static ChannelFactory<IRepositoryService> GetRepositoryServiceChannelFactory( )
{
  lock ( s_sync )
  {
    if ( s_repositoryServiceChannelFactory == null )
    {
      s_repositoryServiceChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IRepositoryService>( Properties.Settings.Default.ConfigName );
    }
  }
  return s_repositoryServiceChannelFactory;
}
```

...and then, when you want a service instance...

```
public IRepositoryService GetRepositoryService( string configName )
{
  return GetRepositoryServiceChannelFactory( ).CreateChannel( );
}
```

Yup, that `IRepositoryService` is a full-blown proxy to your service. Notice the call to create the channel factory used the name of a wcf client config in your client app's config. There are overloads that don't use configuration - where you pass the binding and endpoint yourself. You can go either way.

If you like using the proxies, you can extend them. As you noticed, they're partial classes and you can add useful behavior. I've worked on projects that do this and have been stunned by what a mess can be made from such an approach. I would definitely recommend NOT editing the generated portion. Leave the default constructor alone. Add more constructors and use those...but don't mess with the generated code. You'll be amazed at how many times you need to re-generate your proxies (as your service changes over time).

I use the term *contracts-only .dll* loosely. Data contracts and service interfaces can be *redefined* in your service, if necessary...as long as the type names and structure matches (for data contracts) and method names and signatures match (for service methods). Sometimes it's useful for the types on the client to have different behaviors than the types on the service. It becomes a bit of a hassle to to keep disparate types in sync. In the projects I'm working on, we try to keep everything in the contracts .dll and reference it in the services and the clients. There are versioning-related issues that come up from time to time, but it's been useful for us.

This article will give an overview of using channel factories:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that step 2 says to run the svcutil.exe to create the equivalent of our contracts-only .dll. Svcutil.exe will build data contract classes and interface types based on what's in the service. This can be a great starting point if you already have a service.

Comment: Clay, I think your answer has a lot of explanation. But since I am new to WCF I couldn't understand it much :P. To understand it better can you provide me few links on the technique you are using? Or else I will google it :)

Comment: I'll add a few links

Comment: Clay, I went through [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/558163/Difference-between-Proxy-and-Channel-Factory-in-WC) and what I understand is that ChannelFactory is useful when you have full access to both the service and client dll. I don't have access to the service dll.

Comment: Yeah - this approach is largely for scenarios where you're doing both sides. Of course, generating the proxy and then "stealing" the guts of it is effectively the same thing. The problem is if/when updates to the service occur, you have to manually synchronize the changes. That's the same problem as directly editing the generated proxy...but without the potential of accidentally refreshing the proxy and losing your changes.